# Do new XCode versions contain ALL frameworks in the XCode.app package?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

With XCode 3 it seemed like frameworks were stored in a separate dir. Now I've upgraded to 4.5, should I update my project to look for all standard frameworks inside XCode itself?

With additional frameworks (such as Cg) does anything change with those, or can I put them wherever I wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the title question answer is Yes. All standard frameworks (SDKs) are now placed into the XCode.app package. If you examine the contents of package, you can see folders `Frameworks` and `Other Frameworks` in `Contents` folder of the XCode package.

Your additional frameworks you can place everywhere, but not in XCode.app package (this package is replaced each time during update process).